# Проверка наличия определённого текста в окне приложения

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywinauto

Мне нужно, чтобы код запускал приложение, проверял, есть ли в окне этого приложения определённая фраза и выводил True или False. Собственно, с запуском приложения проблем нет, с выводом я разберусь, а вот с проверкой наличия текста я в тупике. Пробовал это сделать с помощью pywinauto, но как-то не разобрался

Comment: попробуйте OpenCV на распознавание текста потыкать. например https://habr.com/ru/post/466565/  в вашей задаче проще-сравнить картинку с вводом и картинку с верным вводом.

Comment: Уточните задачу. "В окне" это где? Равносильно ли это поиску текста на изображении? Или у вас Edit какой-то с текстом?

Comment: @dIm0n да, это равносильно поиску текста на изображении. Примерно понял, что нужен код, который делает скрин по координатам, где находится текст, и сравнивает его с образцом, после чего выводит значение False или True. Но как сравнить изображения? Или вывести текст из изображения?

Comment: @Sterri сверху уже привели библиотеку. Машинное обучение в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза "как-то не разобрался" звучит очень неконкретно, поэтому и ответ будет общий (надо постить, что именно пробовал). Если `Inspect.exe` текст не видит, то pywinauto не поможет (это первое, с чем стоит разобраться). Вот тут всё написано: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html (или на Хабре: [видео-лекция](https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/336476/) или [текстом](https://habr.com/ru/post/323962/)).

Для распознавания картинок по шаблону есть Python библиотека lackey: https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey (она как раз и использует OpenCV).